# derivative function and twice differentiable of piece-wise function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}x^{a}& \text{if } x\geq 0 \\ 
 0& \text{if } x<0 \end{matrix}\right.$$

1. For which values of $a$ is f differentiable at zero? is the derivative function continuous?

-- In order for this to be differentiable at zero, $a > 1$ must hold. For the second part, how do we know whether derivative function is continuous? isn't derivative of  $f$ at $0$ is $0$? thus continuous

2. For which vales of $a$ is the function twice differentiable.

I guess if $a>1$, f is twice differentiable at $0$ and it seems like for $x>0$ or $x<0$ f is twice differentiable for all $a$. If this is right, how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Let $a>1$

   $$f'(x)=\begin{cases}0 &\text{if }x<0\\ax^{a-1}&\text{if }x\ge 0\end{cases}$$

   So yes, the derivative is always continuous for $a>1$, *basically* because $f'(0)=0$ matches both the limits from the left and from the right of $f'$.
2. Well, you just need to use on the function $f'$ the considerations you made in the first part, and see for yourself whether you are right or wrong, no?

Comment: I am still unsure what happens if x>0 or x<0 . if x=0, we can say that f is twice differentiable as long as a>1. In fact, it sees that in case x>0( or x<0), this function is twice differentiable regardless of value of a

Comment: If $a\le 2$, then $a-1\le 1$, so $f'$ is not differentiable in $0$ if $1<a\le 2$. Indeed, you have no problem whatsoever for $x<0\vee x>0$.

Comment: could you explain why f` is not differentiable at 0 if 1<a<2 ? does that mean that f is not twice differentiable at 0?

Comment: For the same reason that makes $f$ not differentiable at $x=0$ for $a\le 1$. Moreover, if $f'$ is not differentiable in $0$, then obviously $f''(0)$ does not exist.